# Can I get the auto complete window when ssh'd into a server running emacs?

Tags: eshell, ssh

If I have a virtual machine, and I ssh into that machine, then start emacs: (so at this point I am  looking at my terminal emulator, which is showing the command line version of emacs on the other machine)

is it possible to get the things which need some visual-ness (such as the autocomplete popup menu or multiple cursors etc.)?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a classic case of TIAS ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you give Tramp a try? Then you could work on the virtual machine, using your local Emacs.

Comment: A little elaboration would help - e.g. a reference to some part of the Tramp doc or mention of a particular function or option that is appropriate.

Comment: I like and am aware of this ability however the point of the question was it I weren't at my local emacs could I ssh into my local computer and get the same interactivity

Comment: You can always perform "ssh -X ..." to another host. If you start emacs on that host, it will be shown in your local X11, with its graphical UI.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Most of the Emacs UI can be represented in textual terminals.  Images, squiggly lines and advanced display engine features (like pixel-perfect positioning) don't work though.

Comment: So in this case I would just need the drop down generating things like tern and Jedi installed on the remote machine?

Answer (score 0):

company-mode implemented the popup UI in shell. You can use company-mode instead if you are seeking an auto-complete alternative.

If you are interested in elisp coding, check company-tooltip-xxxx in company.el.

If all you want is a simple popup working in shell, check https://github.com/auto-complete/popup-el